# Backwards direction of Cauchy Criterion for Sequences of Functions

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences, sequence-of-function

I am reviewing the proof of the Cauchy Criterion for sequences of functions and have a question regarding the backwards direction.

**Statement:** Let $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and $(f_n)$ be a sequence of real-valued functions with domain $A$. Then $(f_n)$ converges uniformly if and only if $\forall \epsilon >0$, $\exists N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $m,n\geq N$ and $x\in A$ implies $|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|<\epsilon$.

**My question:** For the backwards direction, we know that for each $x$ the sequence $(f_n(x))$ converges (to say $L_x$), but how do we know there is a single $N$ such that $n\geq N$ implies $|(f_n(x)-L_x|, |f_n(y)-L_y|<\epsilon$ for any choice of $x,y\in A$? The difficulty I am having is that the $N$ given in the proof of the Cauchy criterion for real sequences is dependent on the subsequence chosen (I am assuming a proof that uses the BW theorem). An answer is appreciated, but I would prefer a hint at this point to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $\varepsilon>0$, and take $\varepsilon'\in(0,\varepsilon)$. Then there is a $N\in\Bbb N$ such that$$m,n\geqslant N\implies|f_m(x)-f_n(x)|<\varepsilon'.$$ But then, if $n\geqslant N$,\begin{align}|L_x-f_n(x)|&=\left|\lim_{m\to\infty}f_m(x)-f_n(x)\right|\\&\leqslant\varepsilon'\\&<\varepsilon.\end{align}

Comment: I have some concerns about the rigor, mainly when I see your last absolute value expression, but I think I see the meaning. Choose $N'\geq N$ so that $n\geq N'$ implies $|f_n(x)-L_x|<\epsilon/2$ and let $r\in (0,\epsilon/2)$ be such that $|f_n(x)-L_x|=r$. From here $n\geq N$ implies $|L_x-f_n(x)|\leq |f_{N'}(x)-f_n(x)|+r$. Is this the intention of that expression?

Comment: No. I wrote *exactly* what I meant. And I see no lack of rigor in it.

Comment: Could you clarify on what is being said when we write $\left|\lim_{m\to \infty} f_m(x)-f_n(x)\right|\leq \epsilon '$? I do agree that eventually $|f_m(x)-f_n(x)\leq \epsilon '$, but I am not quite seeing how this inequality rigorously translates to this.

Comment: We have $\left|\lim_{m\to\infty}f_m(x)-f_n(x)\right|=\lim_{m\to\infty}|f_m(x)-f_n(x)|$ by continuity. And, since $|f_m(x)-f_n(x)|<\varepsilon'$ for each $m\geqslant N$, we have $\lim_{m\to\infty}|f_m(x)-f_n(x)|\leqslant\varepsilon'$.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I should note I proved the first equality in your latest comment a different way (not sure what you meant by continuity).